# how to show dialogs in android taking screen orientation changes into account

Tags: android, dialog, screen, orientation

this is driving me crazy.  i have read the documentation for creating dialogs in Android and it seems to make sense, except when the screen orientation changes.

I have Activity.onCreateDialog()
where I create the dialog.

I also have Activity.onPrepareDialog()
where I prepare the dialog.

Then in my Activity.onCreate() method,
I call showDialog(id)

that's all well and good and behaves properly.  now comes the tricky part.  I rotate the screen.  it destroys the activity and creates a new one.  Activity.onCreate() gets called, which in turn calls showDialog(id), but there's already a dialog out there, so it winds up calling onCreateDialog() twice and onPrepareDialog() twice.  What is the best approach here for managing a dialog when the screen orientation changes and you need to call showDialog in Activity.onCreate ?

Answer (score 1):

You can save your dialog instance in the bundle inside the method `onSaveInstaceState` and show the dialog again inside the method `onRestoreInstanceState`

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("dialog", DIALOG_ID);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(savedInstanceState.containsKey("dialog")){
        showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
    }
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this would help.  it would still wind up calling onCreateDialog and onPrepareDialog twice...

Comment: problem solved: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/bf4c7798ee378d2

Comment: I imagined that you would know that! Sorry for didn't providing the onCreate method....

Answer (score 1):

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/bf4c7798ee378d2

As stated on that page:

> Change to:
>
> ```
> public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
> {
>    ....
>    //  bundle is null on first start, non-null on restart
>    // [rather than just "if (condition is true)"]
>    if (condition is true && bundle == null)
>        showDialog(42);
>    ....
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your Dialog as a  singleton .

```
static class MyProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog 
    {

    private static MyProgressDialog dialog = null;

    static MyProgressDialog newInstance( Context context )
    {
        if ( dialog == null )
        {
            dialog = new MyProgressDialog( context );


        }
        return dialog;
    }
    static MyProgressDialog getInstance()
    {

            return dialog ; 

    }

    public static  void destroyInstance()
    {
        if(dialog!= null && dialog.isShowing() ){
        dialog.dismiss(); 

        }
        dialog= null;
    }

    private MyProgressDialog( Context context )
        {
        super( context );
        }


    }

    @Override
   protected void onDestroy()
    {
    super.onDestroy();

    if ( progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing() )
    {

        progressDialog.dismiss();

    }
    if( MyProgressDialog.getInstance()!= null){
      MyProgressDialog.destroyInstance();
    }
```

}

Answer (score -1):

if you don't care about rotation you can create your own code for managing this:

Manifest Change:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:configChanges="orientation">
```

Comment: if I don't care about rotation?  i care about orientation changes.  that's what makes this complicated.